# RelativeLayout with TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

I want to create a layout for my spannable view. (View inside EditText)
It consists of an ImageView and a TextView.

It should look like this:

[image]

What I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="0dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closeImg"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/closecross" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/remarkText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="this text will not be shown :("
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/closeImg"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The designer shows it correctly, but at runtime I dont see any text. Whether I assign text in code or directly in the layout

How to display it, like I have shown it in the Image above?

Comment: post your custom view where you are trying to access above layout

Comment: I actually cannot do this. I'm using xamarin for visual studio + c#. It is a bigger class. nevertheless I also have a linear layout that holds one textview. if i use this, it displays properly.

Comment: use weight.....

Comment: @Csharpest look at my answer it will help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `drawableRight` in your `textview`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:padding="0dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/remarkText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/closecross"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/closecross"
    android:text="this text will not be shown :("
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/closeImg"
    android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Look now your text is visible along with the image. (I had put my own image just replace is with yours)
[image]

Comment: Damn, this does indeed show an image. but strangely, the image is being cut off. only ~60% of the width is visible of it. any ideas? This might also come from the spannable builder im using

Comment: I have fixed it!!! thank you so much, the cutting was due to some ancient code...

Comment: @Csharpest glad I could be of help. Happy Coding :)